# How to Make Loop Query with Update in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to make Loop for Update Query in Mysql. But I still didn't find the best way to make the query.

The query I'd like to make is similar like this.

```
SET  @num := 0;
UPDATE my_table a SET a.numbering = @num := (@num+1) where a.year = 2020 and a.id_unit = 1;
SET  @num := 0;
UPDATE my_table a SET a.numbering = @num := (@num+1) where a.year = 2020 and a.id_unit = 2;
SET  @num := 0;
UPDATE my_table a SET a.numbering = @num := (@num+1) where a.year = 2020 and a.id_unit = 3;
SET  @num := 0;
UPDATE my_table a SET a.numbering = @num := (@num+1) where a.year = 2020 and a.id_unit = 4;
SET  @num := 0;
UPDATE my_table a SET a.numbering = @num := (@num+1) where a.year = 2020 and a.id_unit = 5;
```

But I want to make it with Loop if that's possible to do, like this.

```
SET @x = 0;

SET @num := 0;
WHILE
    ( @x < 40 ) DO
    UPDATE my_table a 
    SET a.numbering = @num := ( @num + 1 ) 
WHERE
    a.year = 2020 
    AND a.id_unit = @x := ( @x + 1 );

END WHILE;
```

Comment: I advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide text formatted example data and text formatted expected results.. By the way MySQL does not allow looping in plain SQL only on stored programs like procedures, functions and triggers but iam pretty sure you can do it without stored programs

Comment: Or can i use procedure or function to execute that query? Cause I have to execute hundred rows, it'll be so wasting the time if i make it one-by-one

Comment: yes you can, that's exactly what Raymond was telling you.

Comment: indeed @ADyson and topicstarter using a number generator and joining that with you table data is probably (much) faster then using a LOOP in a stored procedure. Just provide example data and expected results.. Nobody can help you correct if you don't provide help us helping you.